# Terminating app uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I get the following error in the console:

> Terminating app uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRrzd.png)'

I get this error when I am selecting an image to be added to firebase. This happens in the code bellow.

```
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

//            let imageToUse = PhotoArray()

//            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPickedImage) //here convert to data

            PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray.append(userPickedImage)  //append converted data in array

            imageView.image = userPickedImage
//-----------------------------//
//            //begin code from firebase docs
            // Create a root reference
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

            // Create a reference to "mountains.jpg"
            let ImgRef = storageRef.child("ImgRef.jpg")

            // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
            let userImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/userImagesRef.jpg")

            // While the file names are the same, the references point to different files
            ImgRef.name == userImagesRef.name;            // true
            ImgRef.fullPath == userImagesRef.fullPath;    // false

            // Local file you want to upload
            let localFile = URL(string: "path/to/image")!

            // Create the file metadata
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

            // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
            let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: metadata)

            // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
            uploadTask.observe(.resume) { snapshot in
                // Upload resumed, also fires when the upload starts
            }

            uploadTask.observe(.pause) { snapshot in
                // Upload paused
            }

            uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
                // Upload reported progress
                let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                    / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
            }

            uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
                // Upload completed successfully
            }

            uploadTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
                if let error = snapshot.error as? NSError {
                    switch (StorageErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)!) {
                    case .objectNotFound:
                        // File doesn't exist
                        break
                    case .unauthorized:
                        // User doesn't have permission to access file
                        break
                    case .cancelled:
                        // User canceled the upload
                        break

                        /* ... */

                    case .unknown:
                        // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
                        break
                    default:
                        // A separate error occurred. This is a good place to retry the upload.
                        break
                    }
                }
            }


        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The error appears to happen on line 76 as shown bellow.

[image]

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: put the traces and check which line of code is actually causing the error

Comment: well the SIGERT shows up in my app delegate class so I will try and find it

Comment: I updated teh question with what I belive to be teh spot where teh error occurs

Comment: Are you implementing .pause(), .resume() and .cancel() functions on your uploadTask?

Comment: not that i am aware of

Comment: If you're not using those functions or looking for that behavior then the uploadTask.observe methods are not needed as they only fire when using the functions in my comment. i.e. if you .pause your upload, then the observe.pause fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API. `URL(string` is for URL strings starting with a `scheme` (`http://`, `ftp://`, `file://`).

For files in the local file system you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:` which takes a string path starting with `/`.

Comment: I have tried:             let localFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/image")
 and the same thing with the / at the front. However I continue to get the same error

Comment: Of course the URL (string) must be valid. A hard-coded URL string does not work.

Comment: I tried userImagesRef.downloadURL but get the following error: Cannot convert value of type '(@escaping (URL?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase. It looks like you are using a closure. Anyway the argument of `URL(fileURLWithPath:` must be a valid **string** path starting with a slash.